# Practical management of user config data in an MVVM application

Tags: c#, mvvm, config, desktop-application

I'm developing a desktop application that serves as an IDE for our customers. This application allows the user to configure and integrate our programmable devices into their products.

I'm looking for best practices/design patterns for managing persistent data in an MVVM app like this. Some data is potentially reusable between the users' projects, so I'd like to store those pieces independently, rather than in one big file. This scenario has led me to consider the way Visual Studio handles this (a .csproj file that points to the files that make up the project).

When considering the Visual Studio approach, I can easily implement an object like this for my own data and serialize it into XML. However, when it comes to opening and manipulating the files that this project file points to, I am really struggling to find an elegant solution.

For instance, I open my project file, deserialize it, and I'm left with an object containing the paths, as well as some metadata like CompanyName, ProductName, and so on. Next step: open/deserialize each of the files pointed to in the project file... But where should those objects live? How should you notify the ViewModels that the model was changed externally? Intuition tells me that there should only be one instance of any unique model to avoid issues with copies falling out of sync, but that's all I've got.

Perhaps there's a framework available for this?

There is probably a good article or SO answer to this, but I couldn't figure out how to search for it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as "How should you notify the ViewModels that the model was changed externally?", the answer is `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, for that to work, my Model would need to be a property on some class, and that class would have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (sounds like a ViewModel). My question is, what class is my Model a property of? Reminder: I have _multiple_ ViewModels tied to a given Model, so I don't see how your answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings that are specific to the application should be stored using the normal settings that's built into Visual Studio and .Net (Settings tab on project properties). This will provide you will versioning, upgrading, etc.

Settings that are specific to each project would need to be stored in the project itself.

To be a good corporate citizen, you should create a folder off of the user's Documents directory and then each project might have its own sub folder if it has multiple artifacts, or I guess just a flat directory if everything about the project is a single file.

The other part of your question was unclear. Are you talking about how a .cs file can be edited externally to VS and VS reloads it automatically? If so, you'd just set up a file change notification watch when you open a project.

EDIT:

View models should generally not have references to each other, unless you are referring to POCOs that implement INPC as a "view model" which I don't really. View models to me is basically the data context for a XAML view.

In terms of VMs communicating with each other, its best to keep it loosely coupled and use the messenger pattern. Most MVVM frameworks have a messenger implementation. You DI a IMessenger or whatever interface they use into your VMs and then `IMessenger.Subscribe<OpenMessage>()` (syntax obviously varies among MVVM frameworks, but in general you get a message of type X and add an event handler or call the send method) for example and get notifications of that type. The VM that is initiating the message would new up an OpenMessage and send it to the messenger to distribute it to the VMs that want it.

For your CsProj scenario, you would need to store those settings in the project file and deserialize.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I intended in my question. What I meant was, when I open an existing file, and then deserialize it and assign it to the Model, how should I notify all of the ViewModels that reference that Model? In all previous applications I have developed, they were simpler and all access to the Model was done through the ViewModel. Here, I have multiple ViewModels accessing one Model.

Comment: Also, my question is not about application settings. Consider the Visual Studio analogy: I want my users to be able to create their own projects (like a .csproj file), add various types of new items to their projects (like .cs files in a C# project), as well as reuse those items between multiple projects (like adding existing .cs source files as link to a C# project).

Comment: @automagically - See my updated answer. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've read about the Messenger Pattern  (as well as Event Bus) while researching this problem, but I wasn't sure if it was necessary/desirable for my use case. The impression I got was that the pattern makes your application difficult to follow and debug. Have you applied this pattern before? If so, was it workable?

Comment: @automagically I use it all the time. I love it, if you believe that :). It's part of what makes WPF / MVVM "slick" imo. It keeps everything decoupled. Not too hard to debug / follow. One view sends a message out and views that care about it subscribe to the message. Debugging is nothing more then putting a breakpoint on the event handler. The decoupling is great if you change views around.

Comment: @automagically - in the messenger implementation that I use, it includes a sender VM, so you know exactly who sent it if you have multiple senders sending the same messages. You can also do things like timestamps on the messages or a universal counter if you are concerned about message order debugging. Most implementations also have sync & async implementations for fire & forget or if you need a response.